# Taylor Series in Fractional Calculus

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

I recently studied fractional calculus, namely the possibility to define fractional derivatives of some functions, like

$$\frac{\text{d}^{1/2}}{\text{d}x^{1/2}}\ f(x) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{\text{d}^{2/3}}{\text{d}x^{2/3}}\ f(x)$$

and so on.

Now the question that came up into my mind is: if such a construction is possible, can we built " *new* " Taylor series for well known function in order to take into account (some) fractional derivatives too?

I know the first problems that would arise would be: how could we take the whole possible derivatives of order between $0$ and $1$? They are infinite. And Yeah, that could be a really huge problem..

Are there any example of **Fractional Taylor Series**?

P.s. I've already read other similar questions, but they are too arid and I didn't find any good answer yet..

Comment: How/Why does the Taylor Series expansion work?  Does the Taylor Series expansion always work?  Why?  Try to apply these ideas on Fractional Calculus (though I don't see it working, due to one of the theories of Fractional Calculus being that a fractional derivative may be independent of close values of the original function, ie they don't work like derivatives, you can approximate the derivative by looking at the graph. Conversely, I imagine it hard to approximate a graph by looking at the fractional derivative.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

[Series expansion in fractional calculus and fractional differential equations](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4819)

[Fractional calculus and the Taylor-Riemann series](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2005/vol6-n1/paper6/v6n1-6pd.pdf)

Examples: see p.7-9 of the first link and p.18 of second link.

Comment: very interesting reference, thanks (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Doing a few calculations, I find the following must be:

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(a)x^{k-n}}{\Gamma(k-n+1)}$$

where we define ${1\over\Gamma(-n)}=0$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

The regular Taylor series doesn't hold by induction, but this one does.

You could probably adjust $k$ to fit what you want.

(note, it fails to converge for most $f(x)$)

Answer (score 2):

An example of the formula for Caputo fractional derivative at zero is
\begin{equation} 
D_0^{\alpha}f(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)\cdot x^{n-\alpha}}{\Gamma(n+1-\alpha)} \text{ where } k=\text{rounded up } \alpha.
\end{equation}

Comment: Your post is quite terse, and this is has undesirable consequences.  For one thing the statement is conclusory, without reasoned mathematical argument to support it.  Even more undesirable is the lack of evident connection to the Question's posed problem ("can we buil[d] *new* Taylor series for well known function[s]").

Comment: This is just an example of fractional Taylor series as was requested.  I can prove the formula but that will take a couple of pages.  Too long for this forum, I think.